# Any way with the .NET membership in C# that I can reset a password

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I am coding an application and I would like to give the admin a way to reset a password. The closest I have come to this is the following:

```
public abstract string ResetPassword(string username, string answer);
```

But this requires I know the answer.

With the .NET MembershipProvider how can I simply reset a password to something else? The only way I can think to do this is to delete the user and recreate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you implement your custom MembershipProvider? if so set RequiresQuestionAndAnswer to false and you will not need to provide the answer in ResetPassword.

Comment: I would like the users to need the RequiresQuestionAndAnswer and the admin to not need that.

Answer (score 0):

see:
http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/recovering-and-changing-passwords-cs

Comment: This answer seems to be more related to ASP. My application is MVC so I don't have all the user controls of ASP.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to add the password recovery feature to an MVC project. I've got a blog post on my site where I detail the code that you need to add to your controller, model, and views:

http://hectorcorrea.com/Blog/Password-Recovery-in-an-ASP.NET-MVC-Project

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to do what you desire using only Membership... I had to use System.DirectoryServices.

Assuming you can get a Directory Entry, try this:

```
public void SetPassword( DirectoryEntry AdEntry, string userPassword )
        {
            ADEntry.Invoke( "SetPassword", new object[] { userPassword } );
            ADEntry.CommitChanges();
        }
```

If you need more help look here :

[Howto: (Almost) Everything In Active Directory via C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx)